# Python: Scipy very slow on Windows10 compared to MacOS

Tags: python, windows, macos, performance, scipy

emphasized texti tried to execute a simple python program on my macbook pro 15 on my two partition: MacOS Mojave and Windows 10.

I use **spsolve** function for solve a sparse linear system on some matrix and I see that the same code with the same matrix is **so much slower** on Windows compared Macos.

For example:

- matrix 1 -> **MacOs**: *29 sec* / **Windows**: 377 sec

On MacOS, when I perform these calculations, the processor goes to **full speed** and I feel the fan turning strong. 
On Windows this does not happen, **the processor remains at 20%**.

I use Python 3 64bit on both systems.

```
from scipy import array, linalg, dot
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve

matrix_names = ['cfd1']

for matrice in matrix_names:
    mat = sio.loadmat('/matrix_path/%s' %matrice)

    A = mat['Problem']['A']
    A=A[0][0]
    matrix_size = np.shape(A)[0]
    xe = np.ones(matrix_size)
    b = A * xe

    start = time.time()
    X = spsolve(A, b) 
    end = time.time()

    print("Times %.6f sec" %(end-start))
```

The slow function is

```
X = spsolve(A, b)
```

Comment: Is numpy installed with mkl support on either of the machines?

Comment: I only use PIP on both the partition. Is the first time I read about MKL, maybe is integrated in MacOs?

Comment: Can you post your cfd1.mat file so I can test it on my computer?

Comment: Yes, you can find cfd1.mat here https://sparse.tamu.edu/Rothberg/cfd1
Same with https://sparse.tamu.edu/AMD/G3_circuit

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem.

The [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl) library is not implemented by default on windows.
I'm not sure that on MacOS it's integrated, however using Anaconda on Windows (which implements Scipy with MKL library) the Python file is executed as fast as on MacOS.